# How to create a new column in pandas dataframe with different replacement of a part of the string in each row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 different columns in different dataframes that look like this.

Column 1 has sentence templates, e.g. "He would like to [action] this week".

Column 2 has pairs of words, e.g. "exercise, swim".

The 3d column has the type for the word pair, e.g. [action].

I assume there should be something similar to "melt" in R, but I'm not sure how to do the replacement.

I would like to create a new column/dataframe which will have all the possible options for each sentence template (one sentence per row):

He would like to exercise this week.

He would like to swim this week.

The number of templates is significantly lower than the number of words I have. There are several types of word pairs (action, description, object, etc).

```
#a simple example of what I would like to achieve

import pandas as pd

#input1
templates = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('AB'))
templates.loc[0] = [1,'He wants to [action] this week']
templates.loc[1] = [2,'She noticed a(n) [object] in the distance']
templates

#input 2
words = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('AB'))
words.loc[0] = ['exercise, swim', 'action']
words.loc[1] = ['bus, shop', 'object']
words

#output    
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('AB'))   
result.loc[0] = [1, 'He wants to exercise this week']
result.loc[1] = [2, 'He wants to swim this week']
result.loc[2] = [3, 'She noticed a(n) bus in the distance']
result.loc[3] = [4, 'She noticed a(n) shop in the distance']
result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create new columns by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with words from `words['B']` and then [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for values for replacement:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\[{}\]".format(re.escape(x)) for x in words['B'])
templates['matched'] = templates['B'].str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False).fillna('')
templates['repl'] =(templates['matched'].map(words.set_index('B')['A']
                                                  .rename(lambda x: '[' + x + ']'))).fillna('')
print (templates)
   A                                          B   matched            repl
0  1             He wants to [action] this week  [action]  exercise, swim
1  2  She noticed a(n) [object] in the distance  [object]       bus, shop
```

And then replace in list comprehension:

```
z = zip(templates['B'],templates['repl'], templates['matched'])
result = pd.DataFrame({'B':[a.replace(c, y) for a,b,c in z for y in b.split(', ')]})
result.insert(0, 'A', result.index + 1)
print (result)
   A                                      B
0  1         He wants to exercise this week
1  2             He wants to swim this week
2  3   She noticed a(n) bus in the distance
3  4  She noticed a(n) shop in the distance
```

Comment: Thanks, will try it out now! I have also added the code for reproducing the inputs in the same format I have them.

Comment: Just tried it out - it does part of the job, but I would like to have the outputs one sentence per line only (maybe in a separate dataframe or a list) - sorry, didn't make it clear in the question. This is necessary for the following steps of my projects. What would be the best way to do it in your opinion? Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I wanted :)